# Issue with opengl load in android virtual device (Ubuntu)

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

i tried to run below command for avd with kvm accleration from Ubuntu 12.04

emulator-x86 -avd jellybean -partition-size 200 -gpu on -qemu -m 343 -enable-kvm

i get the following message before the loading of AVD

emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: libOpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

i guess last error is due to issue in resolution of my screen (1366x768) avd has 800x480 resolution